# Angular table component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I want to develop a table in my Angular web app. Coming from a jQuery world, I had access to plugins like datatable, which was really flexible to customize.

Thinking in Angular components, I have the following two approaches to implement my table, please let me know what approach you have taken and why:

1) A single component for the whole table
2) Individual component for rows. So the table will be a parent component and the rows will be its child component

Comment: i ca  suggest to you this https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/data-table

Comment: I've always used option (1)

Comment: Thank you @federicoscamuzzi

Comment: @ChristianScillitoe How did you handle dynamic behavior on that, for example, if I want to have a button in a row and that the click of the button should get the column data in that row?